# Is the word 'prioritize' used properly?

Tags: word-usage

This is a sentence of an essay:

> A new way of viewing f(RH) as a scattering coefficient weighted average of the f(RH) for each mode was proposed, which helps us **prioritize**  the significance of different modes and better understand f(RH).

I want to express the meaning that this new way of viewing f(RH) can help us to determine which mode is more important and which one is insignificant, can I use the word 'prioritize'? Or are there better words or phrases that can replace it?

Comment: So, a view, which helps you prioritize - what? Not a set, but one or more elements of a set based on some *external* significance. The problem is the view is based only on an average of set attributes, so it is an *internal* thing. You don't prioritize based on internal attributes. Prioritization is *applied* to elements of a set. It can't be sussed out just by analyzing the set. The view helps you assign priority by highlighting the significance of each mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prioritize* doesn't work here. How about *assess*?

M-W:

> [*assess*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assess): to
>   determine the importance, size, or value of

Your example:

> A new way of viewing f(RH) as a scattering coefficient weighted
>   average of the f(RH) for each mode was proposed, which helps us
>   *assess* the significance of different modes and better understand f(RH).

You could also consider *evaluate*, *determine*,  *distinguish*, or *quantify*.

A few comments on your sentence. The verb "was proposed" is too far away from the subject "way". Also, the sentence is overly long. You might want to consider:

> A new way was proposed for viewing f(RH) as a scattering coefficient weighted
>   average of the f(RH) for each mode. This helps (is helping? will help?) us
>   assess the significance of the different modes and better understand
>   f(RH).